# TypeScript Partial<T> type without undefined

Tags: typescript, generics, partial

How to create a *kinda*-`Partial<T>` type, that doesn't allow `undefined` values?

Here's an example:

```
interface MyType {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}

const merge = (value1: MyType, value2: KindaPartial<MyType>): MyType => {
  return {...value1, ...value2};
}



const value = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 42
}

merge(value, {});                          // should work
merge(value, { foo: 'bar' });              // should work
merge(value, { bar: undefined });          // should work
merge(value, { bar: 666 });                // should work
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: undefined }); // should work
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: 666 });       // should work

// now the problematic case:
merge(value, { foo: undefined }); // this should throw an error
                                  // because MyType["foo"] is of type string
```

The type I'm looking for should:

- only accept keys that exist on the generic type (just like a normal `Partial<T>`)
- accept a subset of the keys of the generic type
- **but** don't accept `undefined` if the generic type doesn't accept `undefined` for that key

Is this possible?

---

EDIT: I also created a issue at TypeScript repository, because this is weird and should throw an error at some point: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29701

Comment: Keep in mind that by doing this you may be making your code more difficult for programmatic use; you'd prohibit e.g. `update(value: MyType, new_foo_val?: string) { return merge(value, { foo: new_foo_val })`.

Comment: @Quelklef That's exacty what **should** be prohibited. In your example, when `new_foo_val` is `undefined`, then `merge` will override `value.foo` with `undefined`, which will result in `{...value, foo: undefined}`, and that's not compatible with `MyType`, which specifies that `foo` is always a `string`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**TS 4.4 UPDATE:**

TS4.4 will have [an `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) to give you the behavior you’re looking for directly with `Partial`, as long as you intentionally add `undefined` where you'd like to allow it:

```
interface MyType {
  foo: string
  bar?: number | undefined // <-- you want this
}

const merge = (value1: MyType, value2: Partial<MyType>): MyType => {
  return { ...value1, ...value2 };
}


const value = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 42
}

merge(value, {});                          // okay
merge(value, { foo: 'bar' });              // okay
merge(value, { bar: undefined });          // okay
merge(value, { bar: 666 });                // okay
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: undefined }); // okay
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: 666 });       // okay

// now the problematic case:
merge(value, { foo: undefined }); // error!
// ----------> ~~~
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210717&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjAPZkBcyAzmFKAObHIBGcUA-NSAK4C2raMgA+yXiAAmEGKAiTCAX0KEEZEHWT9ojFAF5kACgBucADa8IARmoZseADTJTFiACZqABQ5hg5gDx2uBAAfACUtljByHohyEQkUBBgvFAg8cgAdNkullZO2Zm57siKANxKKqrqmsUx8SzkVMgA5E0tDizsUNQALG6VhNpQuibmlk74imFlJHPzC4uLAPTLtAAWZLxmksgA7mRQANZDOhBjrpOkFNQt3S2lM0tLqxtbO-uHJ8OjxVfd1Ak0lkIHkj1mz2Qrxom22uwOx1OI3OfwyAOQADYseDIS81jD3vCvkjfuMIFcmrcOmwOICpDI5LtprNobCPgjvmcLhMMpTWtT0ViMTiVvi2UTEYRXiAyHtkGB1igcFAyKwzBB+HBfAhkAg4DQIJQSSiyRSbuJ6SCwcyoWsFcAaG84fL1iq5XB0tAVVAWLi-X7XkI9bwDWgongANoAIiaUYAusgHcgyDB5dE6AwQMxCEA) <-- note, currently you will need to turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` yourself in the TS Config tab; for some reason the url is broken

——--

**PRE-TS4.4 ANSWER:**

It is a known limitation (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195)) that TypeScript doesn't properly distinguish between object properties (and function parameters) which are *missing* from ones with are *present but `undefined`*.  The fact that `Partial<T>` allows `undefined` properties is a consequence of that.  The right thing to do is to wait until this issue is addressed (this might become more likely if you go to that issue in GitHub and give it a  or a comment with a compelling use case).

If you don't want to wait, you can maybe use the following hacky way to get something like this behavior:

```
type VerifyKindaPartial<T, KP> = 
  Partial<T> & {[K in keyof KP]-?: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never}; 

const merge = <KP>(value1: MyType, value2: KP & VerifyKindaPartial<MyType, KP>): MyType => {
  return { ...value1, ...value2 };
}
```

So you can't write `KindaPartial<T>` directly.  But you can write a type  `VerifyKindaPartial<T, KP>` that takes a type `T` and a *candidate* type `KP` that you want to check against your intended `KindaPartial<T>`.  If the candidate matches, then it returns something that matches `KP`.  Otherwise it returns something that does not.

Then, you make `merge()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function that infers `KP` from the type of the value passed into `value2`.  If `KP & VerifyKindaPartial<MyType, KP>` matches `KP` (meaning that `KP` matches `KindaPartial<MyType>`), then the code will compile.  Otherwise, if `KP & VerifyKindaPartial<MyType, KP>` does *not* match `KP` (meaning that `KP` does not match `KindaPartial<MyType>`), then there will be an error.  (The error might not be very intuitive, though).

Let's see:

```
merge(value, {});                          // works
merge(value, { foo: 'bar' });              // works
merge(value, { bar: undefined });          // works
merge(value, { bar: 666 });                // works
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: undefined }); // works
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: 666 });       // works

merge(value, { foo: undefined }); // error!
//             ~~~ <-- undefined is not assignable to never
//  the expected type comes from property 'foo',
```

That has the behavior you want... although the error you get is a bit weird (ideally it would say that `undefined` is not assignable to `string`, but the problem is that the compiler knows the passed-in type is `undefined`, and it wants the type to be `string`, so the compiler intersects these to `undefined & string` which is `never`.  Oh well.

Anyway there are probably caveats here; generic functions work well when called directly but they don't compose well because TypeScript's support of higher-kinded types isn't that good.  I don't know if this will actually work for your use case, but it's the best I can do with the language as it currently is.

[Playground link to code](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8YQN)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I gave thumbs up on the issue. I've used TypeScript and Partial<T> since it came out, but this is the first time I stumbled across this issue.

Comment: Because it requires all the properties and isn't partial at all?

Comment: Nope, see [documentation for mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  `{[P in K]: X}` has a property for each union member of `K`.

Comment: Your `KindaMyType` is the same type as `MyType`.  The fact that you can (unsafely) use type assertions (you are calling this "casting") to narrow `{bar: 666}` to `MyType` isn't the same as the function accepting a partial `MyType`.  I'm surprised you're not mentioning type assertions in your comments since that's the crux of your workaround.

Answer (score 13):

In this case, `Pick` should work.

```
interface MyType {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}

const merge = <K extends keyof MyType>(value1: MyType, value2: Pick<MyType, K>): MyType => {
  return {...value1, ...value2};
}

merge(value, {});                          // ok
merge(value, { foo: 'bar' });              // ok
merge(value, { bar: undefined });          // ok
merge(value, { bar: 666 });                // ok
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: undefined }); // ok
merge(value, { foo: '', bar: 666 });       // ok

merge(value, { foo: undefined });          // ng
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjAPZkBcyAzmFKAObHIBGcUA-NSAK4C2raIQC+hQgjIg6yftEYoAvMgA8AaWQQAHpBAATGsgDWEdGRhosuCAD4AFADc4AG14QAjNQzY8AGmROrhAATNQACsAIRire1v5qNgCUXlZ4yIo2yEQkUBBgvFAgWQB0pYFu7v6lxeUhIgDcouKS0mABLm7pWSzkVMgA5L39vizsUNQALMFNhHJQCo4dEP74Ion1JJtb2zs7APR7yGRGs-IQi0ErpBTU-WP9yGsbu-uHx6fz57VXY9S8+hAYKAIHpHusXiQDkcTnMFt8smwONQAGyosHPCHbKHvWFfJZXXq3YaI8bIf56QHA0FPZDYmFnC5uAk3AbE37IVHI9G7OniXGM5YIwlkgFAkAg7kQqEgRhAA)

Comment: This works just fine, although you lose intellisense support